# Add z value in curve level with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot curve levels with matplotlib, and everything works fine, but I want to show the value of z for every level, how can I add that?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-3,3,500)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,500)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = X**2+Y**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,aspect='equal') 
ax.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=[0,1,4,9])

plt.show()
```

I've tried to look in the documentation, but nothing works.

Comment: Perhaps add contour labels then. I think you get the best examples from: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_label_demo.html

Comment: This is a beautiful reproducible example. Thank you for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to label a seaborn contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169093/how-to-label-a-seaborn-contour-plot)